# Trying to move UIPickerView programatically using constraint but always got this error message

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a simple project to move some components using constraint programatically, in this case it's just a UIPickerView, but unfortunately I always got error code which I really don't understand what's the meaning of it.

here's my interface :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;

@end
```

and here's my implementation :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                      constraintWithItem:_pickerView
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                      toItem:self.view
                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                      multiplier:1.0f
                                      constant:216.f];    
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint];    
}
```

and here's what I see on my debugger console :

```
2013-09-19 10:44:19.582 Constrain2[3092:c07] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x71808f0 V:[UIPickerView:0x7180fd0(216)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x71805d0 V:|-(216)-[UIPickerView:0x7180fd0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7181290 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7184d50 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7181290(416)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7181740 UIPickerView:0x7180fd0.bottom == UIView:0x7181290.bottom>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x71808f0 V:[UIPickerView:0x7180fd0(216)]>
```

why I have error message like this? I also tried this tutorial http://ioscreator.com/auto-layout-in-ios-6-adding-constraints-through-code/ and I found no problem with UIButton. But, it's not using storyboard to create button. while in my case, I'm putting UIPickerView via storyboard. is that what caused the problem?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraint 0x71808f0 wants to set the height of the picker to 216 points.

Constraint 0x71805d0 wants to set the top edge of the picker to 216 points below the top edge of `self.view`.  (This is the constraint you added in `viewDidLoad`.)

Constraint 0x7181740 wants to set the bottom edge of the picker view to be exactly at the bottom edge of `self.view`.

Auto layout can only satisfy those three constraints by making setting the height of `self.view` to 216 + 216 = 432 points.

Unfortunately, constraint 0x7184d50  wants to set the height of `self.view` to 416 points.  Therefore auto layout cannot satisfy all of the constraints simultaneously.

I guess that `self.view` is constrained to be 416 points tall because you're on a 3.5 inch screen (iPhone 4S or earlier), which has a height of 480 points, and you have the status bar turned on (20 points) and either a navigation bar or a toolbar (44 points), leaving 480 - 20 - 44 = 416 points for the view.

Why are you adding the constraint in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Actually I'm still trying to understand how constraints works. That's why I put it into viewDidLoad so that I can easily see after I run it.. Thanks for your answer, Rob.

Comment: hey Rob, I just need to ask you something... if I'm in purpose to hide that UIPickerView below the screen, then by setting constant:416.f won't be a problem, right? what I see in debugger console is just a warning that's not an error message, right?

Comment: Instead of adding that constraint in `viewDidLoad`, make an outlet connected to the bottom constraint (address `0x7181740`).  When you want to hide the picker, change the bottom constraints's constant from 0 to -216.